# Не передается текст между классами

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.7

Всем привет, помогите понять почему не передается текст между классами, программу писали для KIVY, но только через .PY файл, нужно добиться что-бы данные из "self.Product" и "self.Quantity" из класса "ScreenMain", при нажатии кнопки "V", попадали в "self.lbl" и "self.lbl2" класса "ScreenSecond", но этого почему то не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder


class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        ## Создание кнопок "Далее" и "Назад"
        self.main_widget = Widget()
        self.main_widget.add_widget(Button(text='Далее', on_press=self._on_press_button_second_screen, pos = [200, 0], size=(100, 50)))

        ## Создаем первый экземпляр Layout
        self.main_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=45,padding = [30, 0], spacing = 3)
        self.gl_1 = GridLayout(cols=4)

        self.Product = (TextInput(size_hint=[.7, .05], font_size=24, halign='left'))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(self.Product)

        self.Quantity = (TextInput(font_size=24, halign = 'center', size_hint=[None, .1], size=[50, 45]))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(self.Quantity)

        self.gl_1.add_widget(Button(text='V', on_press = self.btn_press_ok, size_hint=[None, .1], size=[50, 45]))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(Button(text='X', size_hint=[None, .1], size=[50, 45]))


        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.main_widget)
        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.gl_1)
        self.add_widget(self.main_layout)


        self.a = ''
        self.b = ''

        self.update_data()

    def update_data(self):
        self.a = self.Product.text
        self.b = self.Quantity.text
        return self

    def btn_press_ok(self, instance):

        self.a = self.Product.text
        self.b = self.Quantity.text
        self.update_data()
        ## Создаем кнопку для добавления дополнительного Layout
        self.gl_1 = GridLayout(cols=4)

        self.Product = (TextInput(size_hint=[.7, .05], font_size=24, halign='left'))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(self.Product)

        self.Quantity = (TextInput(font_size=24, halign='center', size_hint=[None, 0.1], size=[50, 45]))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(self.Quantity)

        self.gl_1.add_widget(Button(text='V', on_press = self.btn_press_ok, size_hint=[None, 0.1], size=[50, 45]))
        self.gl_1.add_widget(Button(text='X', size_hint=[None, .1], size=[50, 45]))

        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.gl_1)
        ScreenSecond().update_data_second()


    def btn_press_del(self, instance):
        self.main_layout.remove_widget(self.gl_1)


    def _on_press_button_second_screen(self, *args):

        ## Создаем функцию кнопки Далее
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        self.manager.current = 'second_screen'


X1_Screen = ScreenMain().update_data()

class ScreenSecond(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a1 = X1_Screen.a
        self.b1 = X1_Screen.b


        ## Создаем кнопку Назад
        self.main_widget = Widget()
        self.main_widget.add_widget(Button(text='Назад', on_press=self._on_press_button_main_screen, pos=[0, 0], size=(100, 50)))
        

        ## Создаем экземпляр Label для отображение введенных данных с первой страницы
        self.main_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=45, padding=[30, 0], spacing=3)
        gl_2 = GridLayout(cols=3)

        self.lbl = Label(text = str(self.a1), font_size = 15)
        gl_2.add_widget(self.lbl)

        self.lbl2 = Label(text = str(self.b1), font_size = 15)
        gl_2.add_widget(self.lbl2)


        self.main_layout.add_widget(self.main_widget)
        self.main_layout.add_widget(gl_2)

        self.add_widget(self.main_layout)


    def update_data_second(self):
        self.a1 = X1_Screen.a
        self.b1 = X1_Screen.b

    def _on_press_button_main_screen(self, *args):

        ## Создаем функцию кнопки Назад
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = 'main_screen'

X2_Screen = ScreenSecond()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ScreenMain(name='main_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenSecond(name='second_screen'))

        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Хмм, поясните, пожалуйста, а где Вы в коде пытались сделать так, чтобы это происходило? Ну, то есть, какие строки кода, по-вашему, должны это обеспечивать?

Comment: Попробуйте переписать немного программы чтобы класс принимал переменные как аргументы, а не использовал в методах инициализацию другого класса. И попробуйте при помощи банального print() отследить на каком этапе ошибка. С kivy не часто работаю но думаю что не в нем ошибка.

Comment: В нашем понимании, при запуске программы создаются пустые переменные "self.Product" и "self.Quantity", далее текст вводиться в "TextInput", нажимается кнопка "V", за ней закреплена функция, которая меняет содержимое "self.a" и "self.b" на значения, которые мы ввели. Далее создается экземпляр класса( в котором нужные значения "self.a" и "self.b"), с ними происходит изменение значения переменных во втором классе "self.a1" и "self.b1", которые в свою очередь отображаются на втором экране в виджетах "self.lbl" и "self.lbl2", задумка была такой, по крайней мере